# Why does ava fail comparing list of objects and list of object literal?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, assertions, ava, deepequals

I'm using the [`deepEqual`](https://github.com/avajs/ava#deepequalvalue-expected-message) assertion, but my test fails

### Test

```
test('should return list of printers', t => {
    const clipboard = filter.asClipboardContent(scan);

    t.is(clipboard, [
        {hostname: '10.0.1.1', port: '9100', description: 'HP 5020-NL'},
        {hostname: '10.0.1.8', port: '9100', description: 'Brother 4002'}
    ]);
}
```

### Fail output

```
 t.deepEqual(clipboard, [{ hostname: '10.0.1.1', port: '9100', description: 'HP 5020-NL' }, { hostname: '10.0.1.8', port: '9100', description: 'Brother 4002' }])
              |                                                                                                                                                   
              [Object{hostname:"10.0.1.1",port:9100,description:"HP 5020-NL"},Object{hostname:"10.0.1.8",port:9100,description:"Brother 4002"}]
```

### Question

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had a type issue, the `port` value was a `string` on one side and an `integer` on the other…

```
test('should return list of printers', t => {
    const expected = [
        {hostname: '10.0.1.1', port: 9100, description: 'HP 5020-NL'},
        {hostname: '10.0.1.8', port: 9100, description: 'Brother 4002'}
    ];

    const clipboard = filter.asClipboardContent(scan);

    t.deepEqual(clipboard, expected);
});
```

In this case, both object are identical.